# Turn a pyqt application into a client-server application

Tags: python, network-programming, pyqt, client-server

I am developping an application using PyQt.
I didn't plan in from the start but I would need to turn this application into a client-server application : centralize the code and have potentially many clients connected to it.

The thing is, I'm very bad in network programming.
Do you know what would be the steps to follow to achieve that ? Or do you know any tutorial that could help ?

I don't know if it is of any importance for that matter but my program accesses a mysql database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Twisted.
It can easily be integrated into PyQt4 and it's a comprehensive network programming library.

Twisted documentation: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Documentation

Reactor that can integrate with PyQt4's event loop: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/attachment/ticket/1770/qt4reactor.2.py

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I just saw something in the FAQ that could be a problem : `Twisted requires a 32-bit version of Python for Windows.` And I am running on 64bits. Is there no workaround that ?

Comment: @Johanna Hmm... Then maybe you could try PyQt4's networking library. It has a clean API and an example can be found here: [link](http://lionel.textmalaysia.com/network-programming-for-python-pyqt4.html) Note how the server accepts connections from the clients and saves the sockets for latter manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was thinking about using this API also. I have one more question though : Is there a wsay to determine which type of client (heavy or thin / installable app or web-browser based) is better / easier to implement ?

Comment: @Johanna It depends on what do you want to do with the clients. Web-browser based client has certain limitations but is easy to implement because different browsers provide uniform interfaces (HTML/JavaScript) so you can focus on designing your app. If you need access to the file system or something else that in-browser JavaScript won't let you do, installable app is the way to go. I would suggest that you should firstly try to build a prototypical server/client pair in pure Python.

Comment: Yes I will need access to the file system, though I don't know yet if an access to the file system from the server will be enough. So thanks for your answer, I'll try to implement a basic client-server app and come back to the forum for more specific questions :)